# Unknown account error while deploying dapp on Ropsten testnet

Tags: truffle, ropsten

While trying to deploy/migrate a dapp to Ropsten I get the following error:

```
C:\CrowdBank-master\CrowdBank-master>truffle.cmd migrate --reset --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0x94e1E6DbEf0936d494B7B23C47F80dfA195e28Fa"
```

I have created the above address (0x94e1E6DbEf0936d494B7B23C47F80dfA195e28Fa) on Metamask, it has a balance of 1 ether.

Here is how my truffle.js file looks like:

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var infura_apikey = "...";
var mnemonic = "...";
var address = "0x94e1E6DbEf0936d494B7B23C47F80dfA195e28Fa"

module.exports = {
   networks: {
      development: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8545,
        network_id: '*' // Match any network id
      },
      ropsten: {
        provider: function() {
           return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/...")
           },
        network_id: 3,
        from: address,
        gas: 4000000
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is a link to the project, its designed for localhost, I modified the truffle.js file to deploy it on ropsten. What else do I have to do?

https://github.com/anshulshah96/LoanDe-centralised

Please help me out on this one.

Comment: Hey Deb, welcome to StackExchange! Although empty, it's not good practice to publish the mnemonic to your Ethereum accounts. Also, the reason Infura generates API keys is to avoid [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attacks. You shouldn't make that public.

Comment: Does the mnemonic correspond to the address? Can you try your address in all lower case?

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, I think if you are using windows, you should be using `truffle-config.js.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the contracts in `build/contracts` and recompiling?

Also, in the mneomic you are including does that correspond to the correct account?

I think your address might belong to a different wallet.

When I deploy via infura, I don't include the address because I think infura will assume it is the first address in the wallet, account[0]

```
 rinkeby: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider(menomic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
  network_id: 4
  //gas: 7600000,
  //gasPrice: 100000000000
},
kovan: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider(menomic, "https://kovan.infura.io/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
  network_id: 42
  //gas: 7600000,
  //gasPrice: 100000000000
},
```

Are you following instructions from https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider?

Comment: The issue was with the address, I removed it from the truffle.js file and added some ethers to the first account in the metamask wallet. It worked.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Also if that worked, I would appreciate if you upvoted my answer, so if other people have the same problem they know to remove their address from their truffle config.

Comment: My reputation is enough yet to upvote someone. sorry!

Comment: lol, upvoted you three times, well best of luck with your dapp development :)

Comment: Still, what if you would want to deploy various contracts and deploy each from a different address?

Comment: At that point I would use scripts to dynamically set a truffle config file

Answer (score 1):

If you use Infura, you do not need Geth. By the way the issue is resolved now.

Here is the github link: https://github.com/dmajumder4292/crowdp2plending

Deployed it on Digital Ocean, here is the URL: http://139.59.20.121:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Have you synced ropsten to your local machine? Is the address in question unlocked?

You should use probably use geth to deploy contracts to ropsten / mainnet. Can Truffle even do that? I've only ever used it to deploy to Ganache.

Hope this helps.